# Where is my Algolia Account Secret and its key?

Tags: firebase, algolia

I am using template (**Full-text search via Algolia**) in Firebase Function.

[See here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search)

At the end of this link you will see > setting up the sample

Here it asks for algolia secret account and key. I have created account at Algolia when I go to my dashboard and select API KEYS then there are many keys.
Unable to know which one is account secret and which one is used as a key?

Please Indicate me secret account and key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "secret" is what we call the "*Admin API key*" in the dashboard and the key must be the "*search only api key*".

Answer (score 2):

The key is the id of your Algolia application.

The secret needs to be an API key that has read and write access (since the functions are doing both indexing and search). That can be your Admin API key or a specific API key you create with these permissions.